# What is the better way to use a custom global library on Angular 8?

Tags: angular8, typescript-typings, angular-library

I want to use a global var name for using a custom library.
I've created one library, it has two services. I want to use with this way `declare var StsLibStorageService:any` on components in application Angular 8.
(sorry bad english)
Because I'm using other apps.js that needs this custom library. The idea is refresh the library in MainApplication, and the micro frontend applications can use it.

On ng build, it creates a lib folder that contains this class:

```
export declare class StsLibStorageService {
private _ls;
constructor();
set(key: string, value: any, expired?: number): void;
remove(key: string): void;
get(key: string): any;
getAllKeys(): string[];
clear(): void;}
```

In MainApplication tsconfig.json, I've added  this

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/sts-lib-crypto/lib",
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

Maybe, on imports script array in angular.json i have to put it, but i dont know how.

Please, if someone knows how to do it, tell me :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use webpack externals for sharing libraries :D